# SoftwareSerial.h library disappears when using intel galileo gen2

Tags: arduino, intel-galileo, software-serial

Everytime I use the intel galileo gen2 with arduino, the SoftwareSerial.h library just vanishes from the list of standard arduino libraries. I've uninstalled and reinstalled new arduino IDEs, checked the libraries and i can clearly see the library present. but the moment I connect my Intel Galileo gen2, it disappears. how do i fix this? I really need to use that specific library.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Help > Cleanup Old Versions` from Visual Studio menu. Otherwise install latest Visual Micro.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SoftwareSerial isn't supported on Intel Galileo boards - a workaround for Gen2 can be found [here](https://github.com/MakersTeam/Galileo/blob/master/Arduino-Examples/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial_GalileoGen2.ino).